# SQL SELECT MATCH AGAINST: not matching the way I need it

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I'm using SQL's MATCH AGAINST for the first time, but I can't get the results I need.
This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fondslijst
WHERE MATCH(Benaming, Verpakking, Auteur01, Auteur02, Auteur03, Auteur04, Auteur05, Auteur06, Auteur07, Auteur08, Auteur09, Auteur10) AGAINST('%dagelijks%')
```

It matches correctly with columns containing `'dagelijks'` and `'dagelijks '` (with a whitespace), but not with columns containing `'dagelijkse'` (with an e). I suspect I need to use some kind of wildcard, but I'm not sure which or how ...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's a MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fondslijst
WHERE MATCH(Benaming, Verpakking, Auteur01, Auteur02, Auteur03, Auteur04, Auteur05, Auteur06, Auteur07, Auteur08, Auteur09, Auteur10) AGAINST('dagelijks *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) you can find some documentation

EDIT: add matching column

```sql
SELECT
      *
    , CASE
            WHEN Benaming LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Benaming'
            WHEN Verpakking LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Verpakking'
            WHEN Auteur01 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur01
            WHEN Auteur02 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur02'
            WHEN Auteur03 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur03'
            WHEN Auteur04 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur04'
            WHEN Auteur05 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur05'
            WHEN Auteur06 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur06'
            WHEN Auteur07 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur07'
            WHEN Auteur08 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur08'
            WHEN Auteur09 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur09'
            WHEN Auteur10 LIKE  '%dagelijks%' THEN 'Auteur10'
    END as MatchingColumn
FROM fondslijst
WHERE MATCH(Benaming, Verpakking, Auteur01, Auteur02, Auteur03, Auteur04, Auteur05, Auteur06, Auteur07, Auteur08, Auteur09, Auteur10) AGAINST('dagelijks *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thnx alot. That's what I needed ;)

Comment: Is there a way to find out which column matched the searchstring?

Comment: The simplest solution can be use a `CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%dagelijks% THEN 'column1_name' WHEN column2 LIKE '%dagelijks% THEN 'column2_name END`

Comment: I've added this solution to the answer above

Comment: Thnx Piccio95. Really appreciate it.